# Using weka to classify sensor data

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka, feature-selection

I am working on a classification problem, which has different sensors. Each sensor collect a sets of numeric values.

I think its a classification problem and want to use weka as a ML tool for this problem. But I am not sure how to use weka to deal with the input values? And which classifier will best fit for this problem( one instance of a feature is a sets of numeric value)?

For example, I have three sensors A ,B, C. Can I define 5 collected data from all sensors,as one instance? Such as,  One instance of A is {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}, and one instance of B is{3,434,534,213,55,4,7). C{424,24,24,13,24,5,6}.

Thanks a lot for your time on reviewing my question.

Comment: What is it that you want to predict? What are the inputs for your prediction?

Comment: The input is various sensor data, which are all numerical values. The output is nominal values. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Commonly the first classifier to try is **Naive Bayes** (you can find it under "Bayes" directory in Weka) because it's fast, parameter less and the classification accuracy is hard to beat whenever the training sample is small.

**Random Forest** (you can find it under "Tree" directory in Weka) is another pleasant classifier since it process almost any data. Just run it and see whether it gives better results. It can be just necessary to increase the number of trees from the default 10 to some higher value. Since you have 7 attributes 100 trees should be enough.

Then I would try **k-NN** (you can find it under "Lazy" directory in Weka and it's called "IBk") because it commonly ranks amount the best single classifiers for a wide range of datasets. The only issues with k-nn are that it scales badly for large datasets (> 1GB) and it needs to fine tune *k*, the number of neighbors. This value is by default set to 1 but with increasing number of training samples it's commonly better to set it up to some higher integer value in range from 2 to 60.

And finally for some datasets where both, Naive Bayes and k-nn performs poorly, it's best to use **SVM** (under "Functions", it's called "Lib SVM"). However, it can be hassle to set up all the parameters of the SVM to get competitive results. Hence I leave it to the end when I already know what classification accuracies to expect. This classifier may not be the most convenient if you have more than two classes to classify.

Comment: What about neural networks ? You say random forests are good with every kind of data, for which algorithm is this not true ? Thanks !